# Maintenance Plan Transaction Log Backup

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, maintenance-plans

I have a backup device set for my transaction log so the sets are contained in 1 file.
I have this set to append, is this correct or should it be overwrite in the plan?
After the full backup is taken and then the next log backup, I still see additional sets in the file.

Update

Ok I tested this an over writing loses all other sets. So is there a way to purge this after a full backup has been taken from a plan?

Comment: I don't like appending - I'd much rather have individual files with the timestamps in the name. Much easier to eyeball, automate, clean up, validate, etc. than when everything is crammed into a single file. However, "should" is quite subjective (I don't use maintenance plans for this or any other task, anyway).

Comment: Your idea of deleting log backup taken before a full backup could prove disastrous if you find your current SQL Server full backup corrupt. You should keep all backup files for more than couple of days